# Disable & gray out tabs without disabling components

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application that writes RFID tags via one of two methods, each of which has a TabControl full of settings for the method, plus a "Start Writing" button.

When a user clicks the Start Writing button, there are some components on the tab page that should stay "live" but the ability to switch tabs should be disabled until writing stops.

Is there a way in WPF to disable and gray out tabs (ie, other than listening for tab changed and switching it back) without disabling the components in the tab?

I want the application to have the "look and feel" of a disabled tab control without disabling, in particular, the "Stop Writing" button.

Comment: Couldn't you just set IsEnabled property of other tabs to False?

Comment: After asking the question, I realized that the proper solution is to move the Begin/Stop Write button to beneath (and outside of) the tab control. Otherwise I would give this a shot. I thought it might be useful to have an answer for academic purposes so I left the question.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because when you click on "Start Writting" button, writing work to RFID tags run on `UI thread`. Create one thread for writing work or add writting code in `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write attached behavior to prevent tab from switching. Additional property bound from *VM or code-behind* will enable blocking functionality:

```
private void OnTabItemSelecting(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs args)
{
     if(!AllowTabChange)
     {
         var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
         var prevId = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(tabControl.SelectedContent);
         tabControl.SelectedIndex = prevId;
     }
}
```

where `AllowTabChange` is a `DependencyProperty` which is bound to corresponding property in *VM* or *code-behind*.
Meantime you'll have to run `BackgroundThread` which will proceed with I/O operations and set `AllowTabChange` to **true** after finished processing.

Comment: I think you missed the "other than listening for tab changed and switching it back" part.